# Magento category import csv

Tags: php, magento, csv, tree, categories

Does anyone have experience with Magento?
I'm trying to import categories from an csv file containing an parent and child id.

### Something like this:

```
PARENTID|ID|NAME
1|3|ITEM 1
1|4|ITEM 2
4|5|CHILD 1
5|8|SUB-CHILD 1
```

Should be:

```
ITEM 1 (id=3)
ITEM 2 (id=4)
   - CHILD 1(id=5)
      - SUB-CHILD 1(id=8)
```

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use MAGMI for import of products & category http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](http://www.magentoworks.net/importexport-magento-category-extension) extension

to import your all category.